# Keras Wrapping Layers and Save

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I created a custom Keras `Layer` with the purpose of wrapping another `Layer` so that I can have some additional computation before and/or after it. Here is some pseudo code:

```
class Wrapper(Layer):

    def __init__(self, layer: Layer, **kwargs):
        super(Wrapper, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._layer = layer

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self._layer.build(input_shape)

        # i.e. following is just an example
        self._after_layer = Dense(10)

    def call(self, x, **kwargs):
        y = self._layer(x)
        y = self._after_layer(y)
        return y

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return self._after_layer.compute_output_shape(self._layer.compute_output_shape(input_shape))

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update({
            'layer': self._layer,
        })
        return config
```

now you can use the above wrapper the following way:

```
y = Wrapper(SomeOtherLayer(...))(x)
```

everything works like a charm, but having a `Layer` as input make impossible to save the model. Trying to save raise a "TypeError: Cannot convert ... to a TensorFlow DType" and it is triggered by the fact that I added `'layer': self._layer,` in the `Layer` config.

Is there any workaraound or best way to achieve the same as above and also save/load the model?

Comment: I think you may not need to update `self._layer` in the `get_config` method because you are already using it in the `call` method and that should be enough to load the computation graph.

Comment: @M.Innat if I do not put it in the config I will get an error later when I load the model (due to missing parameter), if I add it in the config it is like I described in the question.

Comment: In the `layer`, does it have its own get config?

Comment: Yes, `layer` is a standard Keras `Layer` which should implement its own `get_config`.

Comment: No, I mean this one `self._layer = layer`, is this `layer` has its own get config?

Comment: @M.Innat yes it has its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are wrapping a TF layer, you must serialize it in the `get_config`.

You can also implement the classmethod `from_config` which should be able to recreate the wrapper from the output of `get_config`. For this, you will need to deserialize the layer wrapped. This will be useful in case you are saving the architecture and not only the weights.

Here is the full working code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class Wrapper(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, layer: tf.keras.layers.Layer, **kwargs):
        super(Wrapper, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._layer = layer

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self._layer.build(input_shape)

        # i.e. following is just an example
        self._after_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)

    def call(self, x, **kwargs):
        y = self._layer(x)
        y = self._after_layer(y)
        return y

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return self._after_layer.compute_output_shape(self._layer.compute_output_shape(input_shape))

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config["layer"] = tf.keras.layers.serialize(self._layer)
        return config
    
    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        layer = tf.keras.layers.deserialize(config.pop("layer"))
        return cls(layer, **config)
```

Comment: This actually works great! Thanks! It was also easy...